# Asp.net MVC DropDownList Add and Update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am quite new to this as my background is ASP.net Web Form. I am faces with 3 issues as followed:

1. Dropdownlist postback and other dropdownlist is showen once the user selected the 1st dropdownlist.
2. 2nd, I am trying to pass the dropdownlist selected value in adding data

   @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", ViewData["Category"] as List)
3. I am trying to update the data based on the selectedvalue

   @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", ViewData["Category"] as List)

I am able to populate it from the database.
Any advice would be helpful. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.CategoryID, ViewData["Category"] as List<SelectListItem>)
```

and you use FormMethod.Post